# Ways to estimate the rated current of an induction motor without nameplate

Tags: current, induction-motor

I am looking at ways to find the rated current of the motor without the nameplate data. Methods for rated voltage has been found. Assuming that we have the rated voltage, what would be some ways or directions to find the rated current? I have looked into slip but different HP motors have different slip. Unless the motor HP is known, this method cannot be used. Are there any other methods?

Comment: How old is the motor?  I would start by determining the frame size.  Frame sizes should be standard, and will get you in the ballpark.  And the same HP motors have different slip as well, depending on the design efficiency.  The crudest method would be to hook it up to a dynomometer, and start loading it until the speed sags, measure that current, the rated current will probably be around 60% of that, but not guaranteed.

Comment: does the speed sag occur at the maximum (pullout torque) ? I do not think that I am allowed to overload the machine.

Comment: No, the sag would appear at the breakdown torque, which is why I suggest full load rating to be approximately 60% of that point.  Almost all induction motor designs have a breakdown torque of about 160% to 300% of rated torque.

Answer (score 1):

It's useful to measure the winding resistance.

If you use other methods, this method can be used to cross-check the results you get from other methods.

The voltage across a winding divided by that resistance gives you the stall/starting current in that winding. Adjust for star/delta configuration as appropriate.

I(stall) = V / R.

If you have only 2 windings of different resistance, you have a single phase motor : take the lower resistance winding as the "run" winding and use that figure; the other winding is just the start winding.

Now the stall current will typically be between 5x to 10x the rated current, corresponding very roughly to motor efficiencies of 80% (usually small motors) to 90% (probably over 1 horsepower). This is only a guide : if your motor is pulling a train, it may be designed for slightly higher efficiency.

I(rated) = I(stall)/10 up to I(stall)/5.

The same motor may be rated for both 80% efficiency (stall current/5) for (say) 20% duty cycle or 15 minutes, and 90% efficiency (stall current/10) for continuous duty. These are approximate electrical efficiencies; magnetization losses, bearings, friction, windage etc will subtract from them. To estimate those, measure current when running unloaded.

So if you're reverse engineering, with no better source of information, start in this range (say at stall current/10) and use additional parameters such as operating temperature to refine these estimates.

Note that to start the motor successfully, wiring and breakers must be rated to supply the full start current which may be in the 100A region : this does not imply a 100A breaker, but a "motor rated" (class C or D) breaker for your choice of rated current, which will momentarily supply starting current without tripping.

Comment: I don't believe that measuring the stator resistance will be of much use. The stator and rotor leakage reactances will represent the majority of the locked rotor impedance.

Comment: As a consequence, this method is likely to over-estimate the actual stall current, I don't know an easy way of calculating or measuring how much.  It should still be useful as a first approximation to the efficiency when running.

Answer (score 1):

First measure the motor’s shaft diameter. Compare the diameter with published data for similar motors. That should provide a range of likely values for the rated current and torque.

Run a dynamometer test to get data to draw curves for torque vs. speed and current. Before taking data, get the motor near it’s rated operating temperature by running it for an hour or more at the minimum torque of the range that you estimate based on shaft diameter. When running the motor above the maximum torque in the estimated range, take data as quickly as you can to avoid overheating the motor. If possible, use automated data acquisition to get data from locked rotor through breakdown. If you have access to automatic data acquisition equipment, you could take torque and speed data while accelerating a large inertia. If you can record speed data but not torque data, you could calculate torque from the rate of speed change if you know the total motor plus load inertia.

Once you have that data, draw the curve and compare it with published curves or data for motors that might be similar. You can use that method to more closely estimate a range for rated torque.

You might be able to narrow the range by running the motor at various value of torque. At each torque value, run the motor until the temperature stabilizes and perform a temperature rise by resistance test. Unfortunately, that still will not provide an exact value for rated torque and current unless you know the temperature rating of the insulation used for the windings. However, higher temperature insulation is usually used to allow motors to operate in higher ambient temperatures rather than operate at heaver loads. I believe that most motors are designed to operate at 80C temperature rise by resistance.

Comment: Again, this is probably the best way to start.  Determine the actual frame size of the motor.  The frame size is directly related to the design power, and are standard among manufacturers.  Find the frame size, then look up any manufacturers offerings in that frame size.

Answer (score 0):

Induction motors are built for standard power: 0.25kw, 0.37, 0.5, 0.75, 1.1, 2.2, 3, 4, 5.5,...you can deduct the power rating from the size of the motor, then with known voltage you get also the current.

Comment: I have seen 1.5kw also.

Answer (score 0):

As you may be aware, induction motors are available in both single and three-phase versions and in the case of the former, a wide variety of types (e.g. split-phase; repulsion start; capacitor start; capacitor start & run; shaded pole, etc.)

Three-phase motors tend to be of the 'cage-rotor' design and nowadays are physically smaller than much older motors of the same power rating, however comparison of frame size with a known power of contemporary motor will give a good indication.

Assuming your question refers to a 3-phase motor, the connection of the windings (star or delta) also affects the current drawn.  Are you able to measure the phase currents, preferably under load (assuming the motor is already installed)?

The phase currents should be within 5% of each other for a healthy motor, ignoring control circuit consumption.  Typical values of phase currents for star and delta connected motors for 380-440V and 220-240V may be found on the Internet.

Alternatively, if you are able to provide some of the information referred to above, I may be able to give specific values.  Do you intend to run the motor from a conventional starter or an inverter drive?

Comment: yes it is a three phase motor. When loaded, I can measure the phase currents. But unaware of the rated current, when do I exactly know that I am reaching near it. I do have a table from internet which shows typical value for rated current at different voltages depending on the HP of the motor. But in this case, the HP of the motor is also not known.